# How to prevent / auto-deny permission elevation on Windows 10?

Tags: administrator, dialog, elevation

For example, occasionally Oracle Java will randomly lock the screen and ask for elevated permissions to try to install an update. This is extremely annoying when I'm flying a glider online in Condor in VR and the VR suddenly blanks out until this dialog is addressed.

Is there a way to suppress ALL dialogs of this type during times when I *must not* be interrupted?

Comment: No.  You need to do all updates before you leave.  Most updates (>90%) are not more than monthly.

Comment: Before I leave for what? It's my personal PC, I'm playing a game, and I don't give a crap about Java at the time. It sounds like you're talking specifically about Microsoft Windows updates, this is NOT what my question is about.

Comment: @John Also, the need to install updates depends on the particular update. Do I *need* to install *any* of them? Absolutely not, as long as my system is working as I expect, and there are no security risks.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the automatic update of products needs to be done
inside the applications. There is no one way to disable it in
all the products installed in the computer.

For example for Java, you may run the Java Control Panel,
position to the Update pane and set the options suitably.
Perhaps setting "Notify Me" to "Before downloading" would be
enough.
You could disable automatic updates totally (not recommended)
or push them to be less frequent by setting the frequency
to Monthly and specifying a date and time that you won't be
using such games.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I could create another user account just for this purpose, which does NOT have admin rights. Then, by following the steps on this page, it's possible to simply prevent the user from even being prompted.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-disable-admin-prompt-standard-users-windows-10-telenetworks/

1. Open Run (Windows key + R) and type 'secpol.msc' and hit enter.
2. Now, Navigate to Local Policies > Security Options and search for User
   Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for standard user
   and double click on it.
3. Select Automatically deny elevation requests
   and Apply.